# Getting a queue without providing its all properties

Tags: ruby, queue, rabbitmq, message-queue, bunny

I am trying to write a consumer for an existing queue.

RabbbitMQ is running in a separate instance and queue named "org-queue" is already created and binded to an exchange. org-queue is a durable queue and it has some additional properties as well.

Now I need to receive messages from this queue. 
I have use the below code to get instance of the queue

```
conn = Bunny.new
conn.start
ch = conn.create_channel    
q = ch.queue("org-queue")
```

It throws me an error stating different durable property. It seems by default the Bunny uses durable = false. So I've added durable true as parameter. Now it states the difference between other parameters. Do I need to specify all the parameters, to connect to it? As rabbitMQ is maintained by different environment, it is hard for me to get all the properties.

Is there a way to get list of queues and listening to the required queue in client instead of connecting to a queue by all parameters.

Comment: Typically when you interface with a message bus you're supposed to know the contract you need to uphold - doing it dynamically as you're suggesting can create various problems and can be VERY hard to debug.  I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: I second that. You should have the parameters used to set up the queues somewhere in an environment variable and connect to the queue/exchange using those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the :passive=true parameter on queue()? A real example is the [rabbitmq plugin of logstash](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-rabbitmq/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/rabbitmq.rb#L93). :passive means to only check queue existence rather than to declare it when consuming messages from it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation here http://reference.rubybunny.info/Bunny/Queue.html and
http://reference.rubybunny.info/Bunny/Channel.html

Using the `ch.queues()` method you could get a hash of all the queues on that channel.  Then once you find the instance of the queue you are wanting to connect to you could use the `q.options()` method to find out what options are on that rabbitmq queue.

Seems like a round about way to do it but might work.  I haven't tested this as I don't have a rabbitmq server up at the moment.

Comment: For me ch.queues() returns an empty hash though queues are present in my rabbitMQ server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is way to get it with rabbitmqctl or the admin tool (I have forgotten the name), so the info about queue. Even if so, I would not bother.

There are two possible solutions that come to my mind.

*First solution:*

In general if you want to declare an already existing queue, it has to be with ALL correct parameters. So what I'm doing is having a helper function for declaring a specific queue (I'm using c++ client, so the API may be different but I'm sure concept is the same). For example, if I have 10 subscribers that are consuming queue1, and each of them needs to declare the queue in the same way, I will simply write a util that declares this queue and that's that.

---

*Before the second solution a little something:* Maybe here is the case in which we come to a misconception that happens too often :)
You don't really need a specific queue to get the messages from that queue. What you need is **a** queue and the correct **binding**. When sending a message, you are not really sending to the queue, but to the exchange, sometimes with routing key, sometimes without one - let's say with. On the receiving end you need a queue to consume a message, so naturally you declare one, and bind it to an exchange with a routing key. You don't need even need the name of the queue explicitly, server will provide a generic one for you, so that you can use it when binding.

---

*Second solution:*
relies on the fact that

> It is perfectly legal to bind multiple queues with the same binding
>   key
>   (found here https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-java.html)

So each of your subscribers can delcare a queue in whatever way they want, as long as they do the binding correctly. Of course these would be different queues with different names.
I **would not recommend** this. This implies that every message goes to two queues for example and most likely a message (I am assuming the use case here needs to be processed only once by one subscriber).